# Select2 in v3.x and v4.x

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

The code below works with select2 Version: 3.X but when I use "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js" and "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" it does not add the values:

```
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    data.push({id: ""+i, text: ""+i});
}

$("input").select2({
  initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    var selection = _.find(data, function(metric){ 
      return metric.id === element.val();
    })
    callback(selection);
  },
  query: function(options){
    var pageSize = 100;
    var startIndex  = (options.page - 1) * pageSize;
    var filteredData = data;

    if( options.term && options.term.length > 0 ){
      if( !options.context ){
        var term = options.term.toLowerCase();
        options.context = data.filter( function(metric){
          return ( metric.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1 );
        });
      }
      filteredData = options.context;
    }

    options.callback({
      context: filteredData,
      results: filteredData.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize),
      more: (startIndex + pageSize) < filteredData.length
    });
  },
  placeholder: "Select a metric"
});
```

here is the link of jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z7bDG/1/

Comment: Thanks! But what do you need me to explain anymore? I wrote the complete code and problem. I get no errors and the data wouldn't be load to input.

Comment: The link explains clearly and concisely what you need to add.  "'It didn’t work' is not an adequate description for points 3 and/or 4."  Please take the time to read it.